# RewriteRule is not working on all servers because of configuration?

Tags: php, .htaccess

In a folder named *rewrite* I have two files, *.htaccess* and *index.php*

```
<rewrite>
- .htaccess
- index.php
```

In *.htaccess* I have this content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)?$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

and in *index.php*

```
<?php
echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

Isn't supposed when I visit *www.domain.com/rewrite/1234* I would get an output of *1234* ?

Instead of this there is created a file *application/x-httpd-php* for downloading that contains the code of *index.php*

I am trying to figure out why I can not make this happen. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**
I have tested two web servers and local server. Finally it worked on one of the web servers, meaning that it has something to do with the configurations.

What should I do about it ?

Comment: Is your web server setup for PHP?  Make sure it's configured properly.

Comment: I'd assume that the question mark is throwing it off. It's thinking that you have to go to `rewrite/1234?`, instead of `rewrite/1234`.

Comment: @TimCooper You are right. I tried it in another webserver and it worked. So my updated question now is what are these configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is possible that one of your servers hasn't got the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) activated.

To ensure make a test:

In a folder make two files:
- .htaccess
- rewrite.php

In `.htacces` put:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^link([^/]*).html$ rewrite.php?link=$1 [L]
```

and in `rewrite.php` put:

```
<h2 align=center>
<?
if(isset($_GET['link']))
{
    if($_GET['link']==1){echo "Link without use mod_rewrite";}
    elseif($_GET['link']==2){echo "Congratulations!! You has used Apache's mod_rewrite and works well.";}
    else{ echo "Verify the Apache's module mod_rewrite.";}
}
?>
</h2>
<hr>
<head>
<title>Test mod_rewrite in Apache Linux</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test mod_rewrite in Apache Linux</h1>
<p><a href="rewrite.php?link=1">Link one </a> = rewrite.php?link=1</p>
<p><a href="link2.html">Link two</a> = link2.html</p>
<ul>
<li>Test link one</li>
<li>Then test the link two</li>
<li>If with the link two if the link two goes to a not found page then you have not activated the .htaccess or apache mod_rewrite is not working.</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```